# Access virtual machine my remote desktop

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is it possible to access Windows XP on a virtual machine hosted in MS Virtual PC  via Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is make sure that it's getting it's own IP and then enable Remote Desktop on the machine.  It may not work if they share the same interface but if you enable Remote Desktop and then play with the network settings you should get it working without much hassle.